# Impossible to escape php variable in JS alert box

Tags: javascript, php

Sounds stupid but I lost hours to try escaping this php variable that consists post data:

```
$post=array ( 'offers' => '90', 
'pn' => '2', 'ord' => 'price', 'category_select' => '', )
```

and the html:

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="alert('<?php echo $post;?>')">Look</a></td>
```

How to escape it and get the alert with the post data?
Thanks

Comment: Don't you think you are printing a array ....

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What is the desired output?

Comment: yes, the idea is the aray to be printed as js alert box

Comment: `echo $post['whatever index that is'];`

Comment: in the alert box, just print_r($post) ? You can't echo an array.

Comment: this post data takes lots of space on the screen, I want to access post data only if I click on Look link

Comment: @Europeuser: In what format? Format it as a string, ensure that that string is encoded for use within both double and single quotes (`htmlspecialchars` may help), ...

Comment: Guys, thank you for suggestions but all this you suggest above I tried it and it doesnt work. htmlspecialchars just print_r($post) and etc.. Please test the code to see if you success to print it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple parts to this:

1. Convert the array to a string
2. Escape any `'` characters with a backslash, because you're outputting this within a JavaScript string delimited by `'` chars
3. Use `htmlspecialchars` because you're outputting this within an HTML attribute, so any HTML special chars need escaping, in particular (in our case) `"` => `&quot;`

So:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('<?php echo htmlspecialchars(str_replace("'", "\\'", json_encode($post)))?>')">Look</a>
```

How that breaks down:

1. `json_encode` converts the array to a string. You'll probably want to do something else for formatting, but it was a simple way to demonstrate it.
2. `str_replace` converts any `'` in the string to `\\'` to escape them within the JavaScript string
3. `htmlspecialchars` escapes double quotes for us as `&quot;`, since this appears within an HTML attribute that you have in double quotes

Complete test case, with both kinds of quotes:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$post=array (
    'test_quotes' => 'I\'m "feeling" lucky',      
    'offers' => '90', 
    'pn' => '2',
    'ord' => 'price',
    'category_select' => '',
)   
?>
<a href="#" onclick="alert('<?php echo htmlspecialchars(str_replace("'", "\\'", json_encode($post)))?>')">Look</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$post=array ( 'offers' => '90',
        'pn' => '2', 'ord' => 'price', 'category_select' => '', )

?>

<script>
    alert('<?php foreach($post as $key=>$p) { echo $key . ": " . $p . ", "; } ?>');
</script>
```

This works for me, you have to iterate through the array to echo out into the alert.

Comment: this doesnt work for me I get error SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
 

alert('<br />

Comment: You can't HTML inside an alert @Europeuser - try \n.

Comment: Nothing to do with the code I provided, you won't see a single <br /> tag in the provided code above - so please provide us with the full error and the rest of the code so we can try to replicate your actual code.

Comment: You know what you could try? If you want to separate the data? I mean you're using alerts which is already quite bad, so it wouldn't be much worst to do this:

`
<script>
    <?php foreach($post as $key=>$p) { ?>
    alert('<?php echo $key . ": " . $p . ", "; ?>');
    <?php } ?>
</script>
`

Comment: alert('<?php foreach($post as $key=>$p) { echo $key . ": " . $p . '\n'; } ?>'); this code allows a line break at the end of each line.

Comment: @Jack, honestly this is the full code, I have no idea where <br> comes from but with the updated code still same error SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
 

alert('<br />

Comment: @Jackhardcastle: This will fail if there are `"` or `'` in the data.

Comment: What happens if I suddenly put `'\'2'` as the 'pn' key value? ;) Also, hopefully this data is not input-related, else this can be kindly dangerous.

Comment: @ briosheje, no this is used in the admin just for my information.. No risk at all, Sounds easy and stupid task but still no solution.. !